# send javascript date to asp.net server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to send an object by ajax to the asp.net server. There is more datetime property in the object what are not recognised. I mean the datetime in the parameter is the default => 0001.01.01

```
  var a = {start: new Date(), title: "asdf", description: "asdfasdf", allDay: true, end: new Date()};

$.ajax({
            url : m_serverName + "/api/calendar",
            type : "post",
            data : a,
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function() {
                console.log("ok")
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {
                console.log(request)
            },
            xhrFields : {
                withCredentials : true
            }
        });
```

there is just one way, how this works. If I use the toJSON and I send it to the server as JS.

server code:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(CalendarEvent calendarEvent)
        {
            int id = -1;

            var httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["token"];
            if (httpCookie != null)
                if (!int.TryParse(httpCookie.Value, out id))
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, false);
                else
                {
                    int employeeId = service.GetByEmployeeDevice(id).Id;
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                                  service.GetEventsById(employeeId));
                }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, false);
        }
```

domain model

```
 [JsonObject]
    public class CalendarEvent
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("employeeId")]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("partner")]
        public string Partner { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "allDay")]
        public bool AllDay { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "start")]
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "end")]
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
        public int Type { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }

        //navigation property
        //public ICollection<AgentDevice> Devices { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I send this by ajax, without any convertation, because if I have an array with somany object it is very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You could send them as [`ISO 8601`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) strings:

```
var a = {
    start: (new Date()).toISOString(), 
    title: "asdf", 
    description: "asdfasdf", 
    allDay: true, 
    end: (new Date()).toISOString()
};
```

The ASP.NET Web API you are hitting on the server uses Newtonsoft Json serializer which will be able to properly deserialize them to DateTime instances.

Comment: I could use the toJSON method, and the server will recognize it, but if I have an array with more thousands item. Do I have to convert all date property of all of the array items?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a typed list/array...  `List<CalendarEvent>` or `CalendarEvent[]` as your datatype, and it should decode the ISO-8601 encoded dates appropriately.

Comment: I understand, but before I have to convert the date object toJSON, or to ISOString, do not I?

Comment: In JavaScript, when you serialize something with JSON.stringify(...) the default is to serialize date-time instances using UTC/GMT as ISO-8601 style datetime.

Answer (score 0):

the secret is: **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject**(customerJSON);

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]String customerJSON)
        {
            if (customerJSON != null)
            {
                int id = -1;

                var httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["token"];

                Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(customerJSON);


                if (httpCookie != null)
                    if (!int.TryParse(httpCookie.Value, out id))
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, false);
                    else
                    {
                        customer.ContactId = employeeService.GetByEmployeeDevice(id).Id;
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                                        service.Add(customer));
                    }
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, false);
        }
```